# How to diagnose and prevent an http timeout on get with key in RavenDB

Tags: http, timeout, ravendb

Got a problem with a timeout when getting an item by its key in RavenDB client

```
System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
Raven.Client.Connection.ServerClient.DirectGet(String serverUrl, String key)
```

I believe this is due to indexing that is going on in the background - but if that is the case then it should not affect a get by key, should it?

Prior to performing this get I have done a number of inserts that have 6 fields being indexed by Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer.  The fields are only around 300 characters long at most.

We are using one session over each httprequest cycle which I believe is correct.  However we are calling SaveChanges a number of times in the httprequest and are considering calling savechanges only at the end of the httprequest cycle to follow the UnitOfWork pattern.

What would be the best way to diagnose this issue?

Comment: I believe this issue is probably due to calling SaveChanges a number of times per httprequest.  We have changed to call it at the end of the request cycle and will report back results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is NO association between indexing and request handling threads.
One can't impact the other.
Is this hosted on a different machine? Are you doing some debugging that might impact something?
Are you on an EC2 instance?

Comment: Yes it's on EC2 - why? Yes is on another machine with 8080 open. We are not debugging.  Applying SaveChanges at the end of the request cycle appears to have fixed the issue - but I don't know why..